# Implicit conversion in fetch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, type-conversion, pagination, offset-fetch

While studying different query plans to improve performance I noticed that FETCH is doing an implicit convert to `bigint`.

Example table and query:

```
CREATE TABLE checkPagintion
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name NVARCHAR(100)
 )

 DECLARE @paramPageNumber AS INT,
         @paramPageSize AS INT;

 SELECT *
 FROM checkPagintion
 ORDER BY Id
 OFFSET @paramPageNumber ROWS
 FETCH NEXT @paramPageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Execution plan for this query:

[image: Implicit_Conversion]

My question: should I use bigint for all pagination queries? If I use int will it a be a problem since implict_conversion is known for slow performance?

Comment: I don't think you will notice 'slow performance' by a single scalar conversion, but of course if you can use the correct type, why not do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's converting your variables, because `bigint` is what `OFFSET ... FETCH` is expecting for those values. It probably makes sense to

```
DECLARE @paramPageNumber AS BIGINT,
         @paramPageSize AS BIGINT;
```

to avoid any possible performance issues this may cause.

Your `id` column in your table, however, should still be fine as an `int`.

---

From the documentation for [`TOP (Transact-SQL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql):

> ```
> -- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
>
> [   
>     TOP (expression) [PERCENT]  
>     [ WITH TIES ]  
> ]
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> *expression*
>   Is the numeric expression that specifies the number of rows to be returned. *expression* is implicitly converted to a **float** value if `PERCENT` is specified; otherwise, it is converted to **bigint**.

Answer (score 1):

> My question: should I use bigint for all pagination queries? If I use
>   int will it a be a problem since implict_conversion is known for slow
>   performance?

There is no need to use `bigint` for pagination.

And your example query has no need to any convert (but the plan is NOT for your posted query)

Implicit conversion can affect cardinality estimation and that can cause performance issues, but in your case (`OFFSET`..`FETCH`) it makes no difference since this particular conversion in `TOP` operator does not affect cardinality estimation